# Nodejs socket.io and flash example

Tags: flash, node.js, socket.io

Anybody knows of an example using Nodejs socket.io and Flash?

Comment: Here's a [library](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO) of an actionscript implementation of an earlier version of Socket.IO. The README contains an example of how to code up the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

https://github.com/atanasov/FlexWebSocketDemo

Comment: http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=952 - it's use XMLSocket,I want socket.io :s:s:s:s:s:s:s:

Comment: If you want an as3 only example the flex code has all the as3 is in the mxml, its the same thing besides all the markup for the gui stuff. https://github.com/atanasov/FlexWebSocketDemo/blob/master/src/FlexMain.mxml

Comment: All you write right ! but where's the simpler project :(
can you help me to found that

Comment: https://github.com/atanasov/FlexWebSocketDemo/blob/master/src/FlexMain.mxml look in <![CDATA[ copy as3 into your project ]]>